# Which coordinate system will prevent eastern Asia from splitting?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I would like to create a simple graphic for a publication showing all continents (without Antarctica) but I would like Alaska to stand alone and the very eastern tip of Asia to be attached to the main Asia. 
I like the way Sphere_Gall_Stereographic WKID: 53016 Authority: ESRI looks but like WGS84 GCS this CS like many others splits the tip of Asia from the main continent.

In some maps (also in some North American news shows on TV where I noticed this), Asia in fact appears as a single continent and Alaska stands alone. 
Although this may be technically incorrect, visually, I like the continuity.

I tried Robinson projection (both world and sphere) which is what is used in [this World Map](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/CIA_WorldFactBook-Political_world.pdf) but whereas the linked map shows Asia continuous Robinson in ArcGIS splits it apart. I am confused.

Is this something I can Achieve in GIS by using a specific or modified coordinate system or do I just have to export the map to a vector graphic and attach these two pieces manually in post?

Sphere_Gall_Stereographic ESRI WKID: 53016
[image]

WGS84: 
[image]

Robinson in ArcGIS:
[image]

Robinson (World Political Map, Wikipedia):
[image]

Comment: Since the Aleutian Islands are south of eastern Siberia,  it is *not possible* to address this through a coordinate system change. You can clip the individual shapes twice and union the overhangs (shifted 360 degrees) with the appropriate continent, but then you'll have a map which is 380-something degrees wide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shift the central meridian a little.  Changing it to 11 worked for me in projected coordinate systems (Robinson and Gall).

#### Gall

[image: Gall]

#### Robinson

[image: Robinson]

You shift the Central Meridian by right clicking on the projection and choose *copy and modify*, setting the central meridian in this case to 11. In ArcGIS 10.5 this appears in your custom coordinate list.

[image: Creating a custom projection]

Comment: Took the opportunity to add to your answer to show how exactly you change the central meridian.